# How to translate a Windows path for Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking for a way to translate Win32 paths into POSIX paths, preferably using Win32 tools.

**Background**

The latest Windows 10 Insider Build introduced the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) including a native `bash` provided by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu. Their implementation of `bash` goes by the rather complicated name of [*Bash on Ubuntu on Windows*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about), which I will refer to as `bash.exe` in the following.

The equivalent of accessing the Windows path `C:\Users\me\Desktop` in `bash.exe` is `/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop`.

I'm trying to pass a path to `bash.exe` from the Windows Command Prompt (e.g. `bash -c ls /mnt/me/Desktop`). Since that requires me to pass a POSIX path, I was wondering if Microsoft offers any tools to translate Win32 paths programmatically into POSIX paths (like `cygpath` does in Cygwin, or `winepath` on Wine)

**Alternatives**

Unless Windows ships with any tools for translation, I'm open to alternatives to determine the path, e.g. using Node or Python.

Comment: It's clear to me what is being asked, although maybe I'm reading between the lines.   This will eventually be useful to anyone porting cygwin scripts to WSL, ideally in the form of a script or binary that implements similar command line arguments as cygpath.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [WSL Utilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) package now provides this capability via the `wslpath` command.

WSLU is installed by default with the Ubuntu distribution, but may need to be added manually to other distributions.  Instructions for package installation are on the Github page linked above.

Example usage from Bash or other POSIX shells:

```
cd $(wslpath 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop')
```

... will change to `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Desktop`.

The reverse conversion is also possible with the `-w` option:

```
mspaint.exe $(wslpath -w ~/profile.jpg)
```

... will open the file `\\wsl$\<distroname>\home\<username>\profile.jpg` in the Paint application.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a small shell script at [0] which is a beginning and I want to improve over time. I guess "sed" is a good tool to do some string replacements.

Here the current status:

```
linuxify() {
    windowspath=$1
    temppath="$(echo $windowspath | sed -E 's/([A-Z]):/\/mnt\/\L\1/g')"  # C: -> /mnt/c, E: -> /mnt/e
    temppath="$(echo $temppath | sed 's/\\/\//g')"  # backslash -> forward slash
    linuxpath=$temppath
    echo $linuxpath
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
cd "`linuxify "E:\Marvin Kastner\Documents\Uni\Master\gitrepos\masterarbeit_neu"`"
```

[0] https://gist.github.com/1kastner/723a52f352c3eead42988c26b4ade5d0

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I thought the same way like you do and edited my answer even without seeing your comment and minus remark. I was a bit fast to click on the answer button before. Whether the current answer is still worth a minus mark is now up to you.

Comment: It seems that wslpath cannot convert backslash (that is the default path sep in windows), so I need your tool.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474575/how-to-translate-the-wslpath-home-user-to-windows-path and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/

The command line tool `wslpath` does the job now.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @ToTamire's answer.  While I've already edited it to add some information on the usage of `wslpath`, the focus in that answer (as well as all of the previous answers) was in using it from *inside* WSL.

The question that was originally asked here was how to do it in *Windows* (rather than WSL) and "pass a path to `bash.exe`", so let's look at some (new, since the question was originally asked) options for that.  I would still use `wslpath`, but *through* the `wsl.exe` command (which also wasn't available when the question was asked, but replaces the `bash.exe` command for WSL).

Since the question says "from the Windows Command Prompt", we'll use CMD, although I would prefer PowerShell due to its more modern process substitution and quoting/escaping rules.

In CMD:

- *Example 1:*  Convert a Windows Path to WSL/Linux format

  - *Command:*  `wsl wslpath "C:\\"`
  - *Result:* Outputs `/mnt/c`
- *Example 2:*  Convert a Windows Path to WSL/Linux format via `for`

  - *Command:* `for /f %p in ('wsl wslpath "C:\\"') do echo %p`
  - *Result:* Also outputs `/mnt/c`
- *Example 3:*  Use `touch` in WSL to create a file in your Windows home/profile directory (starting from CMD)

  - *Command:*

    ```
    for /f %p in ('wsl ~ wslpath "%userprofile%"') do set wsl_path=%p
    wsl ~ -e sh -c "touch \"%wsl_path%/StackOverflowTest\""
    ```
  - *Result:*  Creates the file `StackOverflowTest` in your Windows home/profile directory

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that NodeJS has a built-in module for this kind of stuff, called `path`. Although it doesn't completely fix the issue at hand, it's a valid workaround (to me). Just `require("path")` and decide on the block or one liner.

Here's the block:

```
var p = require("path")
var path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop"
var sepa = path.split(p.win32.sep)
var newS = [].concat([sepa[0].toLowerCase()], sepa.slice(1))
var newP = "/mnt/" + p.posix.join.apply(p.posix, newS).replace(":", "")
// newP == "/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop
```

As a one liner:

```
var p = require("path")
var d = "/mnt/" + p.posix.join.apply(p.posix, [].concat(["C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop".split(p.win32.sep)[0].toLowerCase()], "F:\\Users\\me\\Desktop".split(p.win32.sep).slice(1))).replace(":", "")
```

Answer (score -2):

The path for your Ubuntu location in the Linux subsystem for Windows is located here:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

Comment: Do **not** under any circumstances use that path in WSL1.  [Per Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) it can cause corruption of the WSL instance.